# Flutter web app not getting any http response

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have finished my Flutter app and it is running fine on both mobile platforms, iOS and Android.

Now I am trying to run the web app on my local Chrome navigator. The app is running but the screens where a http request is needed is not working.

The app uses Firebase and Cloud Messaging. I have solved all Firebase related errors when executing the web app, but the http parts of the app are not getting any response from the web server.

Here you have the index.html file from my project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="proyecto_flutter">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <title>proyecto_flutter</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="splash/style.css">
</head>
<body style="position: fixed; inset: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; user-select: none; touch-action: none; font: 14px sans-serif; color: red;">


  <script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.9/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.9/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAErdmk...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
</script>
  <script>
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // navigator.serviceWorker.register("/flutter_service_worker.js");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
  });
}
</script>
  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
  <picture id="splash">
    <source srcset="splash/img/light-1x.png 1x, splash/img/light-2x.png 2x, splash/img/light-3x.png 3x, splash/img/light-4x.png 4x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light) or (prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)">
    <source srcset="splash/img/dark-1x.png 1x, splash/img/dark-2x.png 2x, splash/img/dark-3x.png 3x, splash/img/dark-4x.png 4x" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
    <img class="center" aria-hidden="true" src="splash/img/light-1x.png" />
  </picture>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to make the web app working just like the mobile apps.

What am I missing?

EDIT

Screenshot from iOS app:

[image]

Screenshot for web

[image]

Comment: This script `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>` is inside your firebase script